# How to replace the ID tag with another contents sharing same ID while parsing with Beaufifulsoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I am parsing several thousands of html pages using beautifulsoup4. I have trouble in finding the contents of each ID and replacing it. The example I uploaded will help you to understand the problem I've encountered.

A simple example of html pages I have is

```
<derivativeHolding>
    <securityTitle>
        <value>Performance Shares</value>
    </securityTitle>
    <conversionOrExercisePrice>
        <footnoteId id="F3"/>
    </conversionOrExercisePrice>
</derivativeHolding>


<derivativeHolding>
    <securityTitle>
        <value>Stock Option (Right to Buy)</value>
    </securityTitle>
    <conversionOrExercisePrice>
        <value>35.57</value>
    </conversionOrExercisePrice>
</derivativeHolding>

<footnotes>
    <footnote id="F3">contents</footnote>
</footnotes>
```

I want to replace "footnoteId id="F3"" which is in between "derivativeHolding" tags by "contents" which is in between "footnotes" tags.

I have no idea in replacing the parts, so I have no code prepared.

I want the result in csv file to be something like this.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gkWd7.png)

where the first row is the list of variable names.

Answer (score 0):

An example solution simply to show a method of finding the footnote if it is referenced:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

r = open('test.html', 'r')
content = r.read()
r.close()
soup = BeautifulSoup(content, 'lxml')

results = []

holdings = soup.find_all('derivativeholding')
for holding in holdings:
    securityTitle = holding.securitytitle.value
    if securityTitle is None:
        continue  # no title?
    price = holding.conversionorexerciseprice.value
    if price is None:
        # check whether there's a footnote reference
        footnoteid = holding.conversionorexerciseprice.footnoteid
        if footnoteid is None:
            continue  # no price or footnote?
        price = soup.footnotes.find('footnote', {'id': footnoteid['id']})

    # join contents incase of empty list or multiple elements
    results.append(str("".join(securityTitle.contents)) + ',' + str("".join(price.contents)))

with open('output.csv', 'w+') as w:
    w.write('securityTitle,conversionOrExercisePrice\n')
    w.write("\n".join(results))
```

It is highly likely you will need to fine tune this to not break on many of your thousands of pages if the html structure varies slightly.